# Android : Locating the item at center position of the screen after selecting it ,In the horizontalscrollview

Tags: android, scroll, center, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to scroll item to the middle position of the screen after selecting it.I have used Horizontalscrollview  and LinearLayout inside it to add item. I show in the XML

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/updown"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalbar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/tlbackground"
                    android:baselineAligned="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>
       </HorizontalScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      hsl = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
      LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.horizontalbar);

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("t"+i);
            ll.addView(b);
        }
     }
}
```

I want something like in figure

**before click**

[image]

**after click**

[image]

**How can I Scroll that selected item to the middle in HorizontalScrollview?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After long try , I have got it with this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    final Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("t" + i);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       int scrollX = (b.getLeft() - (screenWidth / 2)) + (b.getWidth() / 2);
       hsl.smoothScrollTo(scrollX, 0);
    }
});

ll.addView(b);
}
```

Comment: `width` ? Is it some attribute? What does it represents?

Comment: `width` is the whole device screen width you can get it from here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454511/android-get-height-of-the-visible-layout-programmatically/21456000#21456000

Comment: Thank you! You could change to `screenWidth`. It will be more clear, I guess.

Comment: I have set left and right padding to my horizontal scrollview, the clicked position not coming to center,  int padding = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2;
                                horizontalScrollView1.setPadding(padding, 0, padding, 0);
                                horizontalScrollView1.setClipToPadding(false);

Answer (score 4):

This is how your onCreate should look like:

```
hsl = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.horizontalbar);

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
final int width = size.x;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    final Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("t" + i);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int center = (width - b.getWidth())/2;
            hsl.scrollTo(b.getLeft() - center, b.getTop());
        }
    });

    ll.addView(b);
}
```

The only thing i didn't discover is why i need to substract additional 200px (in my case). Probably some padding or something else. Instead of 200, you could discover how many dips is it and call function:

```
public static int convertDipToPixels(Context c, float dips) {
    return (int) (dips * c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Try b.getWidth() instead of b.getLayoutParams().width

Comment: Thanks ,@Zoran for response, But I have got it after some try.

Comment: @ Zoran, where you subtract that additional 200px?

Comment: I have set left and right padding to my horizontal scrollview,  int padding = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2;
                                horizontalScrollView1.setPadding(padding, 0, padding, 0);
                                horizontalScrollView1.setClipToPadding(false);