# RecyclerView large text only center position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I'm using recyclerView.I successfully udaptered string array in my recyclerView.

This is source

```
public class StationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public List<StationsModel> stationsModels;
public Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private String selectedStation = "";

public class GenericViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView stationName;
    public View top, bottom;

    public GenericViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        stationName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.station_item_name);
        top = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.top_line);
        bottom = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_line);

    }
}

public StationsAdapter(Context context, List<StationsModel> stationsModels, String selectedStation) {
    this.context = context;
    this.stationsModels = stationsModels;
    this.selectedStation = selectedStation;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_adapter_item, parent, false);
    GenericViewHolder holder = new GenericViewHolder(view);
    return holder;


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof GenericViewHolder) {
        GenericViewHolder genericViewHolder = (GenericViewHolder) holder;
        if (selectedStation.equals(stationsModels.get(position).getLabel())) {
            genericViewHolder.stationName.setTextSize(40);
            genericViewHolder.top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            genericViewHolder.bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            genericViewHolder.stationName.setTextSize(20);
            genericViewHolder.top.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            genericViewHolder.bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
  genericViewHolder.stationName.setText(stationsModels.get(position).getLabel());

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stationsModels.size();
}

public StationsModel getItem(int position) {
    return stationsModels.get(position);
   }
}
```

Now i try to change text size item,witch 'll be center position in scroll.Is it a possible to do this task with recyclerView? I try to receive like carousel result.
Thanks

Comment: can you post the view of screen?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5r2f.png i mean like this result  @ M. Ashish

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826115/android-locating-the-item-at-center-position-of-the-screen-after-selecting-it).

Comment: This is a horizontal scroll example  @M. Ashish

Comment: So make that vertical naa.

Comment: can you show me how to can do it ? @ M. Ashish

Comment: This what you need i think. [link](https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager)