# Scroll a button to center in Horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, scroll, horizontalscrollview

I am working on an `android application` where I need to show some offers in horizontal scroll view. These offers are in the form of clickable buttons.

Here is the list example:

[image]

**Notes about this pic:**

- This is a horizontal scroll list of clickable buttons.
- This list can have multiple buttons and at a time, we can show only 2 buttons with full width like shown in the pic.

Here is the 2nd pic:

[image]

**Notes about this 2nd pic:**

- This show that one button is in the center.

**What I want:**

I want when user scroll the horizontal list then button that is displayed with full width in scroll view should animate to the center when user removes his hands from scrolling view. With that said, I can scroll by tapping and it should be smoothly but when I leave doing scrolling then the button that seems to come in center should be animated to center position like in 2nd image.

**I tried this given solution but this works when I click on a button.**

[Android : Locating the item at center position of the screen after selecting it ,In the horizontalscrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826115/android-locating-the-item-at-center-position-of-the-screen-after-selecting-it)

> This is exactly similar but I want the button in the center when I
>   leave doing scrolling.

Any help?

Comment: you need to add touch listener to your scroll view to detect if the view is not being touched then add the code which centers the button

Comment: @Badr That I have already tried but it didn't work because we can't detect which button should be in the center out of 3 visible buttons.