# Android Studio scroll to view and center it on the screen?

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to scroll to a specific view and the center the view in the middle of the screen. See the image below.

[image]

If I use

`scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, myView.getBottom());`

then my view aligns at the top of the screen, as the image below shows.

[image]

The view takes place where I've marked with red, behind/above the top menu.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did u tried smth like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826115/android-locating-the-item-at-center-position-of-the-screen-after-selecting-it

Comment: With some adjustments to this, I got it to work. Could not find this on my own, thank you.