# Need to place the clicked item clicked center of the screen, in Horizontal Scrollview

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have populate images dynamically in a linear layout, which is placed inside Horizontal Scrollview. I have enabled auto scroll the horizontal scrollview, with 1 min delay. I have set left and right padding to the horizontal scrollview, as it appears from center of the screen and scrolls to left and end at center of the screen. Auto scroll works fine. My issue is when I click on the images inside the scrollview, I need to bring that image to center of the screen, and continue auto scrolling. I have searched and found answer to place the clicked item center, from the answer for this question [Android : Locating the item at center position of the screen after selecting it ,In the horizontalscrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826115/android-locating-the-item-at-center-position-of-the-screen-after-selecting-it). But in my case, clicked item, not coming to center.

```
final int duration = 1000;
        final int pixelsToMove = 50;
        private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        private final Runnable SCROLLING_RUNNABLE = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {            
                    horizontalScrollView1.smoothScrollBy(pixelsToMove, 0);               
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, duration);            
            }
        };


    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView1 = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
    LinearLayout layLandmarks = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layLandmarks);
    final ImageView[] dynamic_imageView = new ImageView[jsonArray.length()]; 
     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     dynamic_imageView[i] = new ImageView(Activity.this);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
                            dynamic_imageView[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
                            Glide.with(Activity.this)
                                    .load(imageUrl)
                                    .override(30, 30)
                                    .error(R.drawable.button_white_color1)
                                    .into(dynamic_imageView[i]);
                            dynamic_imageView[i].setId(i);
                            dynamic_imageView[i].setTag("landmarkName");
                              layLandmarks.addView(dynamic_imageView[i], i);
                               horizontalScrollView1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                                    int padding = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2;
                                    horizontalScrollView1.setPadding(padding, 0, padding, 0);
                                    horizontalScrollView1.setClipToPadding(false);
                                }
                            });
                               Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                            Point size = new Point();
                            display.getSize(size);
                            final int width = size.x;
                            dynamic_imageView[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                 int center = (width - dynamic_imageView[i].getWidth())/2;
                                    horizontalScrollView1.scrollTo(dynamic_imageView[i].getLeft() - center, dynamic_imageView[i].getTop());
                                    }
                            });
     }
       mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 100);
```

Adding my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/black_transparent_background">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEventTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnBack"
        android:text="Santa Rosa Marathon"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_24" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/camera_icon_white" />


    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/laySeekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/seekBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:background="@drawable/seekbar_layout_background">


            <SeekBar

                android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
                android:visibility="gone"

                />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <HorizontalScrollView

            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">


            <LinearLayout

                android:id="@+id/layLandmarks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/laySeekbarText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnCircle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/seekbar_text_back">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seekBarProgressValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="0 mi"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtVideoElevationValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarProgressValue"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="0 sqft"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/btnCircle"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/seekbar_thumb" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/start_icon" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/videoProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `int center = (layLandmarks.getLeft()- width/2) + layLandmarks.getWidth() /2;
            horizontalScrollView1.smoothScrollTo(center, 0);` try this in onclick method

Comment: @ Krishna, not working.

Comment: What happened ? no changes or bit improved ? share your layout file as well. Try this too `int center = (dynamic_imageView[i].getLeft()- width/2) + dynamic_imageView[i].getWidth() /2; 
horizontalScrollView1.smoothScrollTo(center, 0);`

Comment: Kirshna, added my layout file. trying your updated center code, also not placing the image at center to the screen, placing few points right to its current position. Also I like to mention, I have set padding for the scrollview, as it starts and ends at the center of the device screen.